# Google Game Services: Turn-based Multiplayer bug with automatch criteria

Tags: java, google-play-games, multiplayer

here is my problem: when I try to create a quick turn-based match using google game services, it only works when I set automatch criteria and the min players number equals to the max players number, like this:

```
Bundle autoMatchCriteria = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(N,N,0);
TurnBasedMatchConfig.Builder tbmcBuilder = TurnBasedMatchConfig.builder().setAutoMatchCriteria(autoMatchCriteria);
Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.createMatch(mGoogleApiClient, tbmcBuilder.build())
                          .setResultCallback(new MatchInitiatedCallback());
```

Now, if I don't set automatch criteria (which is allowed according to the description) or set them when min automatch players is not equal to max automatch players, in response from the server I get an error with a status code 6004 STATUS_MULTIPLAYER_ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION.

Does anyone know if it's a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesStatusCodes), the error code means `This multiplayer operation is not valid, and the server rejected it. Check the logs for more information.` Do you have logs to share?

Comment: I checked device logs, found nothing there. Is there some "special happy place" where I can see logs from the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the problem. It didn't work because I set max automatch players to 8 and apparently 7 is the limit.